# How to register CyberSource.WSSecurity.dll on MS azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage

I am implementing payment gateway named as Cybersource  to my project.
Please follow this link for more info http://www.cybersource.com/developers/integration_methods/simple_order_and_soap_toolkit_api/

I am using `simple_order_and_soap_toolkit_api`, and this requires WSE to be installed. I have installed the WSE. Application is working fine on my local machine but when published the site on Microsoft Azure server http://azure.microsoft.com/ an error occurs. Error detail are as following :-

```html
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {698BFD43-76AA-4D13-98FE-5BE9FF5E05B8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {698BFD43-76AA-4D13-98FE-5BE9FF5E05B8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {698BFD43-76AA-4D13-98FE-5BE9FF5E05B8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {698BFD43-76AA-4D13-98FE-5BE9FF5E05B8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]
   CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature..cctor() +18

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for &#39;CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature&#39; threw an exception.]
   CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature.get_Version() +24
   CyberSource.Clients.NVPClient.SetVersionInformation(Hashtable request) +77
   CyberSource.Clients.NVPClient.RunTransaction(Configuration config, Hashtable request) +48
   RaftingScene.Web.Areas.PublicSite.Controllers.PublicGearController.PayToCheckOut(String Amount, String Currency, String cardname, String cardnumber, String cvv, String exdate) +560
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass42.&lt;BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod&gt;b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8`1.&lt;BeginSynchronous&gt;b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass39.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4f.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously&gt;b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass37.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2a.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1d.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +155
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36215

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[COMException]: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {698BFD43-76AA-4D13-98FE-5BE9FF5E05B8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature..cctor()
[TypeInitializationException]: The type initializer for &#39;CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature&#39; threw an exception.
   at CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature.get_Version()
   at CyberSource.Clients.NVPClient.SetVersionInformation(Hashtable request)
   at CyberSource.Clients.NVPClient.RunTransaction(Configuration config, Hashtable request)
   at RaftingScene.Web.Areas.PublicSite.Controllers.PublicGearController.PayToCheckOut(String Amount, String Currency, String cardname, String cardnumber, String cvv, String exdate)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->"
```

I am getting error because of this DLL file `CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature`

I searched on google and found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1071492.aspx?COM+problem+Retrieving+the+COM+class+factory+for+component
so i need to register the `cybswssecurity.dll` as they mentioned in the post  `Try running Regsvr32 cybswssecurity.dll`. I tried the Debuging Console of azure  https://raftingscenewebdev.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole but got Access denied error. I have logged in as administrator but still getting the Access denied error. Is there any other option to register the cybswssecurity.dll? How can i manage the file security or user access to files on azure? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using azure websites, azure websites doesn't support registering COM components on a machine (as well as no GAC support for .net dll's)
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/

You should use VM's or use the PaaS cloud services, where you have full control of the machine.

Comment: I did tried it on my local IIS server, its throwing the same error. I following this link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/ I need to figure it out, I think is somthing related to WSE.

Comment: Could be some WSE problem, is it exactly the same error (class not registered) on your local IIS?